# Ordinary Least Square, minimise

Tags: least-squares, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to

A regression problem where we have n distincts points, $x_{1}, x_{2},\ldots, x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$. We can treat **observations** as independent random variables $y_{1}, y_{2},\ldots, y_{n}$ depending on the given formula:

$$
y_i = \theta_{0} + \theta_{1}x_i^2 + \theta_{2}\exp{(x_i)} + \varepsilon_i
$$

where $\varepsilon_i$ are distributed as $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Derive the maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta_{0},\theta_{1},\theta_{2}$ .

Maximising $L(y_n | \theta_0, \theta_1, \theta_2)$ is equivalent to minimising  $   \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \theta_0 - \theta_1 x_i ^ 2 - \theta_2 e^{x_i}) ^ 2 $

I am trying to use ordinary least squares to minimise  $   \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \theta_0 - \theta_1 x_i ^ 2 - \theta_2 e^{x_i}) ^ 2 $

but really would want to see a step by step solution to reaching.

Kindest regards

Comment: the answers and approch seems very different tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given obesrvations $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$ and a linear (in terms of parameters) dependence

$$
y_i = \theta_0 + \theta_1x_i^2 + \theta_2e^{x_i} + \varepsilon_i,\quad i = 1, \ldots, n, 
$$

one can consider a new set of observations $(y_1, z_{1, 1}, z_{2, 1}), \ldots, (y_n, z_{1, n}, z_{2, n})$ and a new linear dependence

$$
y_i = \theta_0 + \theta_1z_{1,i} + \theta_2z_{2,i} + \varepsilon_i,\quad i = 1, \ldots, n, 
$$

where

$$
z_{1, i} = x_i^2, \quad z_{2, i} = e^{x_i}.
$$

Thus, we have a 2-variate linear regression problem:

$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{Z}\boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}, 
$$

where

$$
\mathbf{Y} = \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\ldots \\
y_n
\end{pmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{Z} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & z_{1, 1} & z_{2, 1} \\
1 & z_{1, 2} & z_{2, 2} \\
\ldots \\
1 & z_{1, n} & z_{2, n}
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\boldsymbol{\theta} = \begin{pmatrix}
\theta_0 \\
\theta_1 \\
\theta_2
\end{pmatrix},
\boldsymbol{\varepsilon} = \begin{pmatrix}
\varepsilon_1 \\
\varepsilon_2 \\
\ldots \\
\varepsilon_n
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \theta_0 - \theta_1x_i^2 - \theta_2e^{x_i}\right)^2$ is equivalent to minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n\left(y_i - \theta_0 - \theta_1z_{1, i} - \theta_2z_{2, i}\right)^2$, which is equivalent to minimizing $\left\lVert\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{Z}\boldsymbol{\theta}\right\rVert^2$, i.e.

$$
\min_\boldsymbol{\theta} L(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \min_\boldsymbol{\theta}\left(\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{Z}\boldsymbol{\theta}\right)^T\left(\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{Z}\boldsymbol{\theta}\right).
$$

The solution to this problem can be found by solving a so-called *score equation*

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol{\theta}}L(\boldsymbol{\theta}) = 0 \Leftrightarrow -2\mathbf{Z}^T\mathbf{Y} + 2\mathbf{Z}^T\mathbf{Z}\boldsymbol{\theta} = 0 \Leftrightarrow
\mathbf{Z}^T\mathbf{Z}\boldsymbol{\theta} = \mathbf{Z}^T\mathbf{Y} \Leftrightarrow \boldsymbol{\theta} = \left(\mathbf{Z}^T\mathbf{Z}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{Z}^T\mathbf{Y}.
$$

Comment: sorry i am not familiar with the 2-variate linear regression was considering a least square method

Comment: This _is_ a least squares method.

Comment: ah yes i can see now what this is a least square method thank you